# H2 and COALESCE with sub-select column, not found

Tags: mysql, sql, h2, coalesce

I have a query that works in MySQL but also needs to function with H2.
The query performs a sub-select to generate a column that is used for ordering. The nulls are replaced with a value so they are set last in the order.
H2 complains about bad grammer that the sub-query column does not exist, it works great with MYSQL. I have MYSQL mode set on the H2.

This is the query:

```
SELECT
    OO.ID,
    OO.UUID,
    OO.BLOCKED,
    OO.CREATED,
    OO.UPDATED,
    (SELECT
        VALUE
    FROM PUBLIC.OOSER_PA
    WHERE (ATT_ID = (SELECT
        ID
    FROM PUBLIC.PAT
    WHERE NAME = 'ooserFirst'))
        AND (OOSER_ID = OO.ID)) AS SORTED
FROM PUBLIC.OOSER OO
ORDER BY =COALESCE(SORTED, 'zzzzzzzzzz')
LIMIT 0 OFFSET 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the query needs to work with two systems, I would suggest that you use a subquery:

```
SELECT oo.*
FROM (SELECT OO.ID, OO.UUID, OO.BLOCKED, OO.CREATED, OO.UPDATED,
             (SELECT op.VALUE
              FROM PUBLIC.OOSER_PA op
              WHERE op.ATT_ID = (SELECT p.ID
                                 FROM PUBLIC.PAT p
                                 WHERE p.NAME = 'ooserFirst'
                                ) AND
                    op.OOSER_ID = OO.ID
             ) AS SORTED
      FROM PUBLIC.OOSER OO
     ) oo
ORDER BY COALESCE(SORTED, 'zzzzzzzzzz')
LIMIT 0 OFFSET 10;
```